# How can I wire up an quad channel amplifier to become stereo with 2 times the power?

Tags: amplifier, sound

I have an TDA7388 IC. This is an quad channel amplifier 40w on every channel. Is it possible to wire it up to become a stereo amplifier with 80w per channel? [Circuit](https://avrlab.com/upload_files/2.GIF)

Comment: That's a quad bridge-tied load. Look up "bridge-parallel amplifier" to learn about how you can combine them in parallel. I think you should be fine because doing this with ICs exactly like yours is a fairly common practice. Look for example cases where your particular IC has been used in a bridge-parallel topology. Someone I'm sure has already done all the lifting for you.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No you can't**

Compare the [TDA7388](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/3d/05/8a/ee/2f/3d/45/f7/CD00179160.pdf/files/CD00179160.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00179160.pdf) (4 x 45 W quad bridge car radio amplifier)

to the [TDA7265](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/20/6b/75/ae/1b/fa/48/cb/CD00000145.pdf/files/CD00000145.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000145.pdf) (25 +25W STEREO AMPLIFIER WITH MUTE & ST-BY)

The TDA7256 can be used both as a stereo amplifier **or** a mono bridge amplifier. Note how the amplifiers basically have **one** output pin, the other side of the speaker is connected to ground.

Note how in the bridged configuration (page 11) the speaker is connected between the two amplifiers.

The TDA7388 also uses **two** pins connected to the speaker. There is no block diagram but I am quite sure it already uses two bridged amplifiers for each output, that's why it needs **two** pins to connect to each the speaker.

Also it runs on 12 V (as used in cars), the only way to get 45 W out of an amplifier running on 12 V is by using a bridged amplifier.

So the TDA7388 is already a bridged amplifier. There's no way to "double bridge" it.

Comment: The TDA7388 is a quad bridged amplifier, with 4 bridged outputs. Any attempt to double-bridge it will let out the smoke. +1